# How to interpret function prototypes with two different sets of arguments

Tags: c, curl, openssl

In OpenSSL I'm seeing various function prototype definitions that look like this:

```
// from openssl/ui.h
int (*UI_method_get_reader(const UI_METHOD *method)) (UI *, UI_STRING *);
```

In cURL `UI_method_get_reader` is then called like this:

```
return (UI_method_get_reader(UI_OpenSSL()))(ui, uis);
```

This is confusing me because apparently `UI_method_get_reader` is passed two different sets of parameters here: the result of `UI_OpenSSL()` is passed in `method` but then the code also somehow passes the `ui` and `uis` parameters to the very same function.

The prototype definition of `UI_method_get_reader` looks somewhat similar to a function pointer declaration. I know I can do things like this in C:

```
int (*addfunc)(int a, int b);

static int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    addfunc = add; printf("%d\n", addfunc(5,6));
}
```

But still the fact that there's another parameter to `UI_method_get_reader` is confusing me. I have never seen something like this before. Can somebody shed some light on what is going on here and what actually happens in this call taken from cURL:

```
return (UI_method_get_reader(UI_OpenSSL()))(ui, uis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int (*UI_method_get_reader(const UI_METHOD *method)) (UI *, UI_STRING *);` declares `UI_method_get_reader` to be a function that takes a `const UI_METHOD *` and returns a pointer to a function that takes a `UI *` and a `UI_STRING *`.

`UI_method_get_reader(UI_OpenSSL()))(ui, uis)` calls `UI_method_get_reader`, passing it the return value of `UI_OpenSSL()`. `UI_method_get_reader` returns a pointer to a function, which this code then calls while passing it `ui` and `uis`.

You can rewrite `int (*UI_method_get_reader(const UI_METHOD *method)) (UI *, UI_STRING *);` as:

```
typedef int FunctionType(UI *, UI_STRING *);
FunctionType *UI_method_get_reader(const UI_METHOD *);
```

and you can rewrite `return (UI_method_get_reader(UI_OpenSSL()))(ui, uis);` as:

```
const UI_METHOD *method = UI_OpenSSL();
FunctionType *FunctionPointer = UI_method_get_reader(method);
return FunctionPointer(ui, uis);
```